# ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium ChromeDriver v2.40, Chrome version 67.

```
var driver = Browser.GetChromeDriver();          
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var abc=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='pdp-size-select']"));
var aaa=wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='pdp-size-select']")));
abc.Click(); // failed because elementisnotvisible
```

the above two findelement works fine, can get value but **cannot click** because the element is not visible

so i go on to try ExpectedConditions, and no luck with this:

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='pdp-size-select']")));
```

Above code returns:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 10 seconds'
```

Does it have any backward compatibility issues with Chrome v67?

Comment: Try with Thread.sleep(); Whether its work or not, There is no dependency with ChromeDriver

Comment: thanks, i gave it 30 seconds to sleep but it does not work. I've got the same situations long ago and so far no real solutions to it. not sure why.

Comment: Please make sure, Web page is redirected properly and its completely loaded. Also, You can go through with Debugger to stack trace.

Comment: yes, it's completely loaded. the site loads very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error **elementisnotvisible** seems you are pretty close. Moving forward as you are trying to invoke **`Click()`** on the element, so instead of *ExpectedConditions* as `ElementIsVisible()` you need to use [**`ElementToBeClickable()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='pdp-size-select']"))).Click();
```

With out any reference to `SeleniumExtras` and `WaitHelpers` the line of code will be:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='pdp-size-select']"))).Click();
```

**Note**: As you mentioned you are using **Chrome v67.x** ensure that you are using **ChromeDriver v2.40** (but not *ChromeDriver v2.4*)

---

### Update

Debugging further it seems the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you have adapted, identifies exactly two (2) elements within the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). So you need to construct a unique locator to identify and click the desired element as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@data-track-action='Product-Page']//following::select[@id='pdp-size-select']"))).Click();
```

**Note**: The desired element is a `select` element and if you desire to interect with the `<select>` element as per *best practices* you need to use the [**SelectElement**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm) Class from [**OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI.htm) Namespace.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_?

Comment: it's https://www.6pm.com/p/u-s-polo-assn-stretch-pique-dot-print-polo-shirt/product/9068753  an Amazon site.

Comment: actually my real code is driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='pdp-size-select']"))[0].Click); but somehow the first element is not visible and not clickable.