# FindElement() throws System.ArgumentException using Selenium through C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

This is my first Question here, so please bare :)

I am trying to get the Selenium Webdriver to wait until an Element is visible, if not it should use the else.

This is my code, throwing system.argumentexception the path is not of a legal form.

```
if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ember20"), timeout).Displayed)
{
           doXX();
}
else if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ember19"), timeout).Displayed)
{
          doXX2();
}
```

```
    public static class WebDriverExtensions
    {
        public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by)).FindElement(by);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use a try catch instead of if/else

Comment: the thing is, the element exists it doesnt even seem to wait for the element to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ArgumentException Class

[ArgumentException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception?view=netframework-4.8) is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid. Details:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
[System.Serializable]
public class ArgumentException : SystemException
```

---

### FindElement Method

[`FindElement()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElement.htm) method takes only single argument and is defined as follows:

```
IWebElement FindElement(
    By by
)

Parameters:
    by
        Type: OpenQA.Selenium.By
        The locating mechanism to use.

Return Value:
    Type: IWebElement
    The first matching IWebElement on the current context.
```

---

### This usecase

In your code trials you have attempted to send 2 arguments to `FindElement()` method as follows:

```
if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ember20"), timeout).Displayed)
```

Hence you see **system.argumentexception**

An ideal way would had been to send only the `By` parameter as an argument as follows:

```
if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ember20")).Displayed)
```

However, this line of code would also have raised [NoSuchElementException](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_NoSuchElementException.htm) as the `Id` attribute **`ember20`** is dynamically generated through [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) and the numeric part would be dynamic.

---

### Solution

A canonical approach would have been to lookout for the **visibility** of the element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) for the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) as [`ElementIsVisible()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) using either of the the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("CssSelector_identifying_the_element_uniquely")));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("XPath_identifying_the_element_uniquely")));
  ```

---

### Additional Consideration

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853798/expectedconditions-elementisvisible-returns-timeoutexception-even-when-element-i/50855181#50855181)

Comment: Hi! The Solution still throws the same error. appreciate your time!

Comment: @NecronomiconCoding Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, in my case the nuget-package *Costura* was the problem. The package bundles all referenced .dlls and embeds them into the exe.

I removed all dependencies and uninstalled the package, now it's finally working!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the seleniumwebdriver is not on correct path. Please check that selenium webdriver  and support dlls are on correct path.

Comment: Hi, the webdriver starts fine. Crashes only when this method is being used.