# C# Selenium WebDriver GetAttribute not working using Nuget

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate a website with Selenium, however GetAttribute is behaving weirdly. Whatever element I try to getattributes, I get the error below.
I am not sure why it would be trying to get something from the System.IO.

I isolated the code, tried using IWebDriver and ChromeDriver, nothing worked.

```
ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(Util.Util.GetHomeDir() + "/eztools/drivers/");
chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://dfe-portal.svrs.rs.gov.br/NFE/CCC");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
IWebElement el1 = chrome.FindElementById("CodUf");
Log.Debug("el1:" + el1);
Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.TagName);
Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.GetAttribute("data-val"));
```

Error:

```
em System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   em System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.FileUtilities.GetCurrentDirectory()
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.ResourceUtilities.GetResourceStream(String fileName, String resourceId)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.GetAtom(String atomResourceName)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.GetAttribute(String attributeName)
   em ezrpa_runner.Cmds.Logic.WebCaptcha.run(CommandDomain cmd) na C:\ez\vs2019\ez-inspect\ezrpa-runner\Cmds\Web\WebCaptcha.cs:linha 44
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to locate the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) set as `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Id*:

  ```
  //IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("CodUf")));
  //Incase you are using Nuget
  IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("CodUf")));
  Log.Debug("el1:" + el1);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.TagName);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.GetAttribute("data-val"));
  ```
- Using *Name*:

  ```
  //IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("CodUf")));
  //Incase you are using Nuget
  IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("CodUf")));
  Log.Debug("el1:" + el1);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.TagName);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.GetAttribute("data-val"));
  ```
- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  //IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("select[name='CodUf']")));
  //Incase you are using Nuget
  IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("select[name='CodUf']")));
  Log.Debug("el1:" + el1);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.TagName);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.GetAttribute("data-val"));
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  //IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//select[@name='CodUf']")));
  //Incase you are using Nuget
  IWebElement el1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//select[@name='CodUf']")));
  Log.Debug("el1:" + el1);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.TagName);
  Log.Debug("el2:" + el1.GetAttribute("data-val"));
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853798/expectedconditions-elementisvisible-returns-timeoutexception-even-when-element-i/50855181#50855181)

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, still the same issue. On further investigation, I figured Webdriver uses a small "Atom" as they call it to handle it using Javascript executor. Weird thing is that this is the default package from Nuget, so not sure why it is not being able to load this getattribute Atom. That is it throws an issue related to open a file from system path.

Comment: @Geovane Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.