# Selenium Webdriver check if image is displayed using id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been trying to check if an image is displayed on my page using the image id. I have looked through similar posts but cannot find one that solves my problem.

I don't know why my error message says *css selector*, I am trying to find the element using its id.

Any ideas would be great, thanks?

**Test:**

```
public void CheckBannerImage()
{
    var UrlRefLibrary = new UrlStrings();
    string HomeUrl = UrlRefLibrary.GetHomePageLocalHostUrl();
    using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    IWebElement BannerImageElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("HomePageBanner"));

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(HomeUrl);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    Assert.True(BannerImageElement.Displayed);

}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model HomeViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = _loc[Model.PageTabTitle];
}
<div class="text-center">
    @section header_image{
        <div class="bg-img" id="HomePageBanner">
    }
</div>
</div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<body>
    <header>
        @RenderSection("header_image", required: false)
    </header>
</body>
```

**Error:**

```
Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#HomePageBanner"}
      (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
    RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
    <>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
    By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
    RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
    TestHomepageComponentsArePresent.CheckBannerImage() line 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few words:

- Ideally, you need to start finding the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) only after you invoke `Navigate().GoToUrl()`. So the sequence would be:

  ```
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(HomeUrl);
  IWebElement BannerImageElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("HomePageBanner"));
  ```
- Though you have declared an instance of *WebDriverWait* as `wait` you but haven't utilized it while looking out for the element.
- Finally, as per the discussion in [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) other then [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) all the other locator strategies are converted in to [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) while execution.

---

### Solution

To check if an image is displayed on the webpage you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementIsVisible` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *Id*:

  ```
  public void CheckBannerImage()
  {
      var UrlRefLibrary = new UrlStrings();
      string HomeUrl = UrlRefLibrary.GetHomePageLocalHostUrl();
      using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(HomeUrl);
      IWebElement BannerImageElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("HomePageBanner")));
      Assert.True(BannerImageElement.Displayed);
  }
  ```
- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  public void CheckBannerImage()
  {
      var UrlRefLibrary = new UrlStrings();
      string HomeUrl = UrlRefLibrary.GetHomePageLocalHostUrl();
      using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(HomeUrl);
      IWebElement BannerImageElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("#HomePageBanner")));
      Assert.True(BannerImageElement.Displayed);
  }
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  public void CheckBannerImage()
  {
      var UrlRefLibrary = new UrlStrings();
      string HomeUrl = UrlRefLibrary.GetHomePageLocalHostUrl();
      using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(HomeUrl);
      IWebElement BannerImageElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='HomePageBanner']")));
      Assert.True(BannerImageElement.Displayed);
  }
  ```

---

### Update

Incase you are using [nuget](/questions/tagged/nuget) packages you need to use `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions` as follows:

- Using *Id*:

  ```
  IWebElement BannerImageElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("HomePageBanner")));
  Assert.True(BannerImageElement.Displayed);
  ```
- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  IWebElement BannerImageElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("#HomePageBanner")));
  Assert.True(BannerImageElement.Displayed);
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  IWebElement BannerImageElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='HomePageBanner']")));
  Assert.True(BannerImageElement.Displayed);
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevent discussions in:

- [WebDriverWait is not waiting for the element I specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488)
- [ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853798/expectedconditions-elementisvisible-returns-timeoutexception-even-when-element-i/50855181#50855181)

Comment: Thanks Debanjan, the ExpectedConditions is being deprecated. Is there any other way to do this from id without it?

Comment: @DMur Are you using Nuget package?

Comment: Yes I am. Support, WebDriver and ChromeDriver at the moment.

Comment: @DMur Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: That's great, @DebanjanB thanks a million for your help