# Selenium to click a link in href which in <li>

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web

I want to use selenium to click on the "?currentPage=3" for example, on the website itself the button you click redirects to the href, however when I use selenium, nothing happens.
I have tried so many iterations and also looked up similar guides, yet to no avail.

```
<div class="content-area">
        <div class="epub">
            <div class="column epub-nav">
                <div class="epub-nav-inner">
                    <div class="epub-meta">
                        <p>uid: 978-9949-559-55-8</p><p>creator: </p><p>publisher: </p><p>subject: </p>                 </div>
                                <nav epub:type="toc" id="toc">
                <ol>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=3">Tööraamatu kasutajale</a>
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=4">1. Arvuhulgad ja avaldised</a>
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=4">1.1. Arvuhulgad</a>
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=7">1.2. Tehted astmete ja juurtega</a>
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=11">1.3. Ratsionaalavaldise lihtsustamine</a>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

To `Click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `LinkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("Tööraamatu kasutajale"))).Click();
  ```
- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("li > a[href='?currentPage=3']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//li/a[@href='?currentPage=3' and text()='Tööraamatu kasutajale']"))).Click();
  ```

---

### Update

Possibly you need `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `LinkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("Tööraamatu kasutajale"))).Click();
  ```
- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("li > a[href='?currentPage=3']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//li/a[@href='?currentPage=3' and text()='Tööraamatu kasutajale']"))).Click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853798/expectedconditions-elementisvisible-returns-timeoutexception-even-when-element-i/50855181#50855181)

Comment: the ExpectedConditions line is giving me an error

The name 'ExpectedConditions' does not exist in the current context

I am using "using openQA.Selenium.Support.IO;"
and "using openQA.Selenium.Support.IO.ExpectedConditions;" apparently does not exist anymore or is deprecated

Comment: @Chris Checkout the updated answer and ;et me know the status.

Comment: Firstly, i want to thank you for replying even after a answer, i am new to stackoverflow and so far it is so amazing to get in realtime guidance or points in the right direction, i even leave you a like if i had more reputation.
however even now, the same error seems to be happening. I also tried all 3 versions, CSS, xpath and linktext

Comment: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Tööraamatu kasutajale"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)

Comment: @Chris Try the other two locators.

Comment: yeah, my bad i edited it a little bit late, i already did, none of them seem to be working

Comment: Each one essentially gives the same error of Unable to locate element

Comment: @Chris To address **NoSuchElementException** check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940) discussion.