# Unsolved Selenium clicking on a href in <li>

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web

ERROR ON "var links = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/nav/ol/li[3]"));"

I am having trouble clicking a link with selenium that is in a li tag(var links), although it is clickable via hand. I have tried numerous methods, but have yet to find one that works; scouring through stackoverflows already existing problems, has also not been of help.

This is the error I get, no matter what selector type I use
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element

MY CODE

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

    namespace BookFetcher
    {
        public static class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
    
    
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\");
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://xn--epik-0qa.ee/minu-konto/");
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='username']")).SendKeys("");
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='password']")).SendKeys("");
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/p[3]/button")).Click();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).Click();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/section[1]/div[3]/div[94]/p[2]/a"));
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                actions.MoveToElement(element);
                actions.Perform();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                element.Click();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                var links = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/nav/ol/li[3]"));;
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                links.Click();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML SOURCE

```
<div class="content-area">
        <div class="epub">
            <div class="column epub-nav">
                <div class="epub-nav-inner">
                    <div class="epub-meta">
                        <p>uid: 978-9949-559-55-8</p><p>creator: </p><p>publisher: Maurus</p><p>subject: </p>                   </div>
                                <nav epub:type="toc" id="toc">
                <ol>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=3">Tööraamatu kasutajale</a>
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=4">1. Arvuhulgad ja avaldised</a>
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=4">1.1. Arvuhulgad</a>
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <a href="?currentPage=7">1.2. Tehted astmete ja juurtega</a>
                    </li>
```

I already asked for help once, however the solutions provided did not seem to fix the issue, so I thought I would give it a go again, in hopes of someone helping me.

Comment: What line is giving the error?

Comment: I am sorry for not including that in the post originally, I am quite new to stackoverflow and coding itself. It is line 33

Comment: line 33 for you corresponds to this line `links.Click();`?

Comment: var links = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/nav/ol/li[3]"));;

Comment: See the updated answer and let me know if the text you want to click on is printed to the console.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is an iframe.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

namespace BookFetcher
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {


            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://xn--epik-0qa.ee/minu-konto/");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='username']")).SendKeys("");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='password']")).SendKeys("");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/p[3]/button")).Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/section[1]/div[3]/div[94]/p[2]/a"));
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.MoveToElement(element);
            actions.Perform();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            element.Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            var iFrame = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe"));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrame);
            var links = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='?currentPage=4']"));
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            links.Click();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='?currentPage=4']"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)'

Comment: @Chris can you add a link to the previous question you mentioned so I can see what was suggested before that also did not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982298/selenium-to-click-a-link-in-href-which-in-li
Also thank you so much for actively helping, much love!

Comment: @Jortega Possibly OP needs `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.`

Comment: @DebanjanB your answer should have worked.  I am thinking there is something else going on here but without being able to get to the actual page I can only guess.

Comment: @Jortega possibly an `<iframe>`

Comment: I am not even quite sure what where this is being scraped from to be quite honest with you, some of this information posted, does not seem to be anywhere on the page i am looking at.

Comment: @Chris updated the answer to switch to an iframe since the text you are looking for was missing from the print statements.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'Instance' and no accessible extension method 'Instance' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) bookfetcher C:\Users\C\source\repos\bookfetcher\bookfetcher\Program.cs 38 Active

Comment: I feel so stupid having to do this, but it seems like Instance is not apart of OpenQA.Selenium, i tried looking up maybe that i am missing a assembly refrence, but it doesnt seem to be the case, what am i missing. Once again thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Chris updated the answer to switch a different way. `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(`

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)'

Comment: I almost feel bad at this, point asking. I have tried messing around with the code on my own with the directions you guys pointed me towards, but still I have yet to find something that works

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/SwfU5; i put the entire source code of the webpage in a pastebin, so if anybody still cares to help me, they can get a better view. Inded IFRAME is being used, however i dont know how i would select it to get to the real content that i want